# Hiding API keys when deploying a python project to PYPI

Tags: python, security, environment-variables, pypi

I have recently been working on a command line dictionary tool. I am using a spell check and the OED(Oxford English Dictionary) APIs in development both of which naturally require API keys when making calls to the various endpoints. I wanted to ask whether there's a way to hide the keys during deployment to PyPi.

Comment: Have your package's users provide their own API keys.  API keys should be configuration, not code.

Comment: @snakecharmerb The package is ideally meant to be used as is. I did not intend for users to use their own keys, `API keys should be configuration, not code.` this is why i asked the question i wanted to find out if there was a way i could use the API keys without exposing them to the end user(e.g through the code)

Comment: There is no way to do that; if you include the keys in the package then a sufficiently determined user can find them, and use them for whatever they want (or possibly even revoke them).

Comment: user need to put there api keys as requirement,

Comment: First, are you sure you are even allowed to distribute your API keys to 3rd party (the users of your Python project)? I wouldn't be surprised if it was actually a breach of contract to do so. See section 8.2: https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/api-terms-and-conditions?tab=commercial

Comment: @sinoroc, I am well aware of the security concerns and that is the main reason why I asked the question. I wanted to be able to deploy the app while maintaining the confidentiality of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

First, are you sure you are even allowed to distribute your API keys to 3rd party (the users of your Python project)? I wouldn't be surprised if it was actually a breach of contract to do so. See section 8.2of the [Oxford Dictionaries API Terms and Conditions](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/api-terms-and-conditions?tab=commercial)

A general rule, is that if you distribute something no matter how good you hide or encrypt it, someone will find it and decrypt it sooner or later. So just don't do it if you can avoid it.